# fullcalendar fullcalendar not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have filter button and a reset button at the top of my page. When I filter the code works but when I click on the reset button I get the 'fullCalendar not a function error'. I'm using the same code for both. I don't understand why it works once and not any other time.

This is what I'm doing.

```
$(function () {

  /* initialize the external events
  -----------------------------------------------------------------*/
  function ini_events(ele) {
    ele.each(function () {

        // create an Event Object (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)
        // it doesn't need to have a start or end
        var eventObject = {
            title: $.trim($(this).text()) // use the element's text as the event title
        };

        // store the Event Object in the DOM element so we can get to it later
        $(this).data('eventObject', eventObject);

        // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
        $(this).draggable({
            zIndex: 1070,
            revert: true, // will cause the event to go back to its
            revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
        });

    });
  }


  ini_events($('#external-events div.external-event'));

  /* initialize the calendar
   -----------------------------------------------------------------*/
  //Date for the calendar events (dummy data)


  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    buttonText: {
        month: 'month',
        week: 'week',
        day: 'day'
    },
    eventSources: [curSource[0]],

    //events: {

    //    url: "WelcomeModels/Calendar",
    //    data: { Status: `$`('#StatusPicker').val(), BranchNum: $('#BranchPicker').val(), FromDate: `$`('#txtFromDate').val(), ToDate: $('#txtToDate').val(), calendarMonth: month, calendarYear: y },
    //    type: "GET",
    //    error: function () {
    //        alert('Error while Getting events!');
    //    },
    eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
        hasChanged();
        calEvent
        //update the calEvent
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', calEvent);
    },

    height: 'auto',
    contentHeight: 400,
    //hiddenDays: [0, 6],
    editable: false, // this prevents things from being dragged
    droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!
    drop: function (date, allDay) { // this function is called when something is dropped

        // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
        var originalEventObject = `$`(this).data('eventObject');
        // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
        var copiedEventObject = `$`.extend({}, originalEventObject);

        // assign it the date that was reported
        copiedEventObject.start = date;
        copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;
        copiedEventObject.backgroundColor = `$`(this).css("background-color");
        copiedEventObject.borderColor = `$`(this).css("border-color");

        // render the event on the calendar
        // the last `true` argument determines if the event "sticks" (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/)
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);

        // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
        if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
            // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
            $(this).remove();
        }

    }
  });
```

this is the function that gets called by the button's click event.

```
function FilterCalendar() {

  if ($('#txtFromDate').val() == "") {
    date = new Date();
    d = date.getDate(),
    m = date.getMonth(),
    y = date.getFullYear();
  }
  else {
    date = new Date($('#txtFromDate').val());
    d = date.getDate(),
    m = date.getMonth(),
    y = date.getFullYear();
  }
  calendarDefaultDate = date;

  var month;
  switch (m) {
    case 0:
        month = "1";
        break;
    case 1:
        month = "2";
        break;
    case 2:
        month = "3";
        break;
    case 3:
        month = "4";
        break;
    case 4:
        month = "5";
        break;
    case 5:
        month = "6";
        break;
    case 6:
        month = "7";
        break;
    case 7:
        month = "8";
        break;
    case 8:
        month = "9";
        break;
    case 9:
        month = "10";
        break;
    case 10:
        month = "11";
        break;
    case 11:
        month = "12";
        break;
  }
  //get current status of our filters into newSource
  newSource[0] = "WelcomeModels/Calendar?Status=" + $('#StatusPicker').val() + "&BranchNum=" + $('#BranchPicker').val() + "&FromDate=" + $('#txtFromDate').val() + "&ToDate=" + $('#txtToDate').val() + "&calendarMonth=" + month + "&calendarYear= " + y;

  //remove the old eventSources
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', curSource[0]);
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');

  //attach the new eventSources
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', newSource[0]);
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', calendarDefaultDate);
  curSource[0] = newSource[0];
};
```

Comment: could you show the whole  code ?

Comment: is one called above where the fullCalendar function is declared?

Comment: This is my calendar code.

Comment: sounds like jQuery is getting loaded into page again somewhere after you use the plugin first time

Comment: why have some of your `$`s got ` (backtick) characters round them? What does this do? Are you sure that's right? And where's the code which runs your "reset" function? i.e. the thing which is causing the error? Bit hard to work out what's going on if we haven't got the relevant code.

Comment: because when I entered the code snippet into the editor it said I had to put them around the $ so I could submit it.

Comment: that's odd, especially when didn't seem to make you do it for all of the $s. I've never encountered that before. And I've just edited them out successfully for you, to avoid confusion. Anyway, more importantly, you error. The code as shown looks like it should work. I can't see how it wouldn't, unless somehow you've got multiple jQuery and/or fullCalendar instances loaded into the page, or this reset button code is on a different page which doesn't contain fullCalendar (but you've made it fairly clear that isn't the case). Are you able to make JSFiddle demo which reproduces the issue?

Comment: The problem as it turns out was there were multiple jquery loading and it was wiping out the fullcalendar object.